# Should I write constructor for extended Class?

Tags: php, class

The parent class has a constructor like this:

```
function CD_Log( $id = false ) {
    $this->__construct( $id );
}

function __construct( $id = false ) {
    global $cd;

    if ( !empty( $id ) ) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->populate();
    }
}
```

In the extended Class, I want to save some of parent's var and child's var to a different place, also won't use the populate() function. Other than that, the child is constructed the same way as parent. Should I write a contructor for the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are following OOP as you are now, you should remove the global call for $cd, set this as a member var of either the parent or child.

Constructors, as I have seen them commonly used are normally called when you instantiate the object, not through another method of the same class, like the method CD_Log is doing.

For example:

```
$myCdObject = new MyCdClass(); // Automatically calls constructor
$myCdObject->Cd_Log($string);
```

With the above example you are ensure the CD_Log method is only dealing with `log` logic. Unless you make CD_Log a static function, then you can instantiate the class within:

```
public static function CD_Log($id)
{
    $myCdObject = MyCdClass(); // Automatically calls constructor

    // Continue with `log` logic
}
```

To answer your question you probably want a constructor in the child class, which will call the parent constructor explicitly:

```
class parent
{
    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}

class child extends parent
{
    public function __construct($id)
    {
        // Going to take advantage of shared logic
        parent::__construct($id);

        // Now lets do some child class specific stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! by the way, should I use extrends method if the child don't need parent's functions, only need parent's var to perform other jobs when the parent is doing its things?

Comment: If the classes will share any attributes whether it be member vars or methods, it is best to extend.

Comment: Even though you've written everything right - "If you are using OOP" phrase hurts my eyes. OOP cannot be used, it is not a tool, it is the paradigm. You can *follow* it, but not *use*.

Answer (score 1):

If you need - you can override a constructor in child class. But keep in mind that in this case parent constructor will not be called automatically and you need to do that manually `parent::_construct()`

Comment: @zerkmas, thanks! So, I will write a constructor for the child.  The purpose of the child is to use parent's var to  perform other jobs when the parent is called. It will has its own id, so, I should give child's id another name, right?

Comment: @Jenny: I cannot answer to your question due to lack of information of what you're doing there.